# How to get a XSL to display results in multi-columns?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating an application that creates an XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MyCDCatalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
        <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Maggie May</title>
        <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I also a XSL file called MyCDCatalog.xsl (below) that transforms the above XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" />'s <xsl:value-of select="title" /> (<xsl:value-of select="year" />):   $<xsl:value-of select="price" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently, the XSL file returns all the entries in a single column. How do I get my output in 3 or more columns?

I want the output as follows:

```
[cd1] [cd2] [cd3]
[cd4] [cd5] [cd6]....
```

where

```
cd1 = Bob Dylan's Empire Burlesque (1985): $10.90
cd2 = Bonnie Tyler's Hide your heart (1988): $9.90
etc.
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this is to match the **cd** in the first, fourth, seventh (etc) position.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="cd[(position() - 1) mod $columns = 0]" mode="first"/>
```

Where **$columns** is a parameter containing the number of columns

You can then match the **cd** elements in the row by looking at the relevant number of following siblings:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::cd[position() &lt; $columns]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:param name="columns" select="3"/>

   <xsl:template match="/catalog">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2> 
            <table>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="cd[(position() - 1) mod $columns = 0]" mode="first"/>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="cd" mode="first">
      <tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::cd[position() &lt; $columns]"/>
         <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::cd) &lt; ($columns - 1)">
            <xsl:call-template name="emptycell">
               <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$columns - 1 - count(following-sibling::cd)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="cd">
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(title, &apos; &apos;, artist)"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="emptycell">
      <xsl:param name="cells"/>
      <td/>
      <xsl:if test="$cells &gt; 1">
         <xsl:call-template name="emptycell">
            <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells - 1"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan</td>
            <td>Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler</td>
            <td>Greatest Hits Dolly Parton</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>One night only Bee Gees</td>
            <td>Sylvias Mother Dr.Hook</td>
            <td>Maggie May Rod Stewart</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

(I'm only outputing **name** and **artist** here, but I am sure you can see how to change it to show more information)

Note that there is bit of nasty recursive template to output empty cells should the number of remaining **cd** elements be less than the number of columns in the row.

Change the paramater to 4, for example, then the following is output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Empire Burlesque Bob Dylan</td>
    <td>Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler</td>
    <td>Greatest Hits Dolly Parton</td>
    <td>One night only Bee Gees</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sylvias Mother Dr.Hook</td>
    <td>Maggie May Rod Stewart</td>
    <td />
    <td />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Impressive answer .. like always :) I couldn't achieve empty columns .. its much more simpler and indeed better than my answer :) +1

Comment: Umm the output shows up as a single line. However, when I change the out method to html, then it works as desired. Not sure if it was a typo on your part or if I missed something. Also, if I wanted to apply headings or other static text outside of the table, how would I do that? I tried putting it before the <xsl:template match="/catalog"> but then it could not parse the xslt.

Comment: I've changed the output parameter to "html", although it shouldn't actually matter if it is output as a single line or not. I've also some other tags outside the table as an example. As long as what you add is well-formed XML, it should be able to parse.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0, use the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="grp" use="floor(count(preceding-sibling::cd) div 3)" match="catalog/cd"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="catalog/cd[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('grp',floor((position() - 1) div 3))[1])]"
                        mode="group"/>
                    <!-- note: index [1] is superfluous, because generate-id applied on node-set returns the id of the first element in the set -->
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/cd" mode="group">
      <xsl:variable
          name="groupitems"
          select="key('grp', floor(count(preceding-sibling::cd) div 3))"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$groupitems">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="artist" />'s <xsl:value-of select="title" /> (<xsl:value-of select="year" />): $<xsl:value-of select="price" />
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: Muenchian grouping. Constructing the key gave me a little headache, because at first I tried to assign the use attribute a value related to position() - but that does not work properly. I found another thread on this site explaining what to use instead: [key and position() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874376/xslt-key-use-position-problem).

The output is the desired one:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Bob Dylan's Empire Burlesque (1985): $10.90</td>
                <td>Bonnie Tyler's Hide your heart (1988): $9.90</td>
                <td>Dolly Parton's Greatest Hits (1982): $9.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bee Gees's One night only (1998): $10.90</td>
                <td>Dr.Hook's Sylvias Mother (1973): $8.10</td>
                <td>Rod Stewart's Maggie May (1990): $8.50</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. I had never heard of Muenchian grouping before but it seems to be custom made for questions like mine. One semi-related question though - why do different browser display output differently? IE shows output in single line, chrome does't display anything, firefox is the only one that display it correctly.

Comment: I recommend *not* to use this solution. Using the `preceding-sibling::` axis in this way results in slow, O(N^2) execution.

Comment: @TalShyar when I open the html result I get the same in all browsers

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I agree with the order N^2. But...do you have a good suggestion on how to lower this, still using grouping? That would be interesting, as grouping is the first thing that springs to mind when encountering this kind of questions - well, to my mind :-).

Comment: @Maestro13: Just have a look at the answer by Tim C -- it is more efficient. "Grouping" doesn't automatically mean "inefficient". And "grouping" doesn't have to use `count(preceding-sibling::someName)`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Pity, I hoped you as an XSLT Guru would have a better idea for the key definition, removing the need for preceding-sibling from it.

Comment: @Maestro13: Why should I provide a new solution when there is the good solution by Tim C?

Answer (score 0):

Edit3:

The two templates `table_format` and `table_format2` will do the job .. 
set the count in the global variable:

```
  <xsl:variable name="col_count" select="'3'"/>
```

col_count decides number of columns :)

also remember that I have used

```
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[1]">
```

in the first template ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="col_count" select="'3'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[1]">
          <xsl:call-template name="table_format"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="table_format">
    <xsl:param name="count" select="'1'"/>
      <tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="table_format2"/>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="../cd[$col_count + $count]">
        <xsl:call-template name="table_format">
          <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count + $col_count"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="table_format2">
    <xsl:param name="col_count2" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$col_count2 &lt;= $col_count">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist" />'s <xsl:value-of select="title" /> (<xsl:value-of select="year" />): $<xsl:value-of select="price" />
      </td>
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::cd[1]">
        <xsl:call-template name="table_format2">
          <xsl:with-param name="col_count2" select="$col_count2 + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your suggestion does not work or at least it does not do what i want it to do. I want each <cd /> block on a single line. See my example above.

Comment: @TalShyar, now I understood the requirement .. :) after you added those tables .. hang-on a minute your code is getting ready ..

Comment: @TalShyar .. I have added my answer .. it may not perfect .. moreover its XSLT 1.0 solution .. please wait for some more answers :)