# Sort XML node based on another node

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

In XSLT I'd like to call a template, and passing in some content to a template. The content, however, should be sorted in the way the videos are sorted (13-41-61) rather than in the order the contents are sorted (61-41-13).

I have the following XML:

```
<videos>
    <video key="13" />
    <video key="41" />
    <video key="61" />
</videos>


<contents>
    <content key="61" />
    <content key="41" />
    <content key="13" />
    <content key="10" />
</contents>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:call-template name="video">
    <xsl:with-param name="content" select="contents/content[@key = videos/video/@key]" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this easily?

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation seems to be the most efficient of the currently posted solutions -- no `count(preceding-sibling::*)`,  and no `//content[@key=$key]` -- both of which result in O(N^2) -- quadratical time complexity**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kContByAtttr" match="content" use="@key"/>
 <xsl:key name="kVidByAtttr" match="video" use="@key"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contents">
  <contents>
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/videos/video">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kContByAtttr', @key)"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(key('kVidByAtttr', @key))]"/>
  </contents>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML (wrapped into a single top element to become a) document:**

```
<t>
    <videos>
        <video key="13" />
        <video key="41" />
        <video key="61" />
    </videos>
    <contents>
        <content key="61" />
        <content key="41" />
        <content key="13" />
        <content key="10" />
    </contents>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<t>
   <videos>
      <video key="13"/>
      <video key="41"/>
      <video key="61"/>
   </videos>
   <contents>
      <content key="13"/>
      <content key="41"/>
      <content key="61"/>
      <content key="10"/>
   </contents>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting a snippet of code I usually use, it should work

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <contents>
    <xsl:for-each select="//video">
      <xsl:call-template name="sortedId">
        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="@key"></xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </contents>    
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="sortedId" >
    <xsl:param name="key"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//content[@key=$key]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Result is:

```
<contents>
  <content key="13" />
  <content key="41" />
  <content key="61" />
</contents>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need to use `<xsl:call-template>`? If you just want to sort the `<content>` elements in the order the `<video>` elements are in, you could do something like this:

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--
  Index <video> elements according to their position in the tree.
  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876074/825783
  -->
  <xsl:key name="kVideo" match="video"
    use="count(preceding-sibling::video) + 1"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--
      Apply attributes (fallback to account for the extra <content> element)
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!--
      Apply the @key attribute of the <video> element that's in a
      position corresponding to the position of this <content> element
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kVideo', position())/@key"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<root>
  <videos>
    <video key="13"/>
    <video key="41"/>
    <video key="61"/>
  </videos>
  <contents>
    <content key="61"/>
    <content key="41"/>
    <content key="13"/>
    <content key="10"/>
  </contents>
</root>
```

#### Output

```
<root>
  <videos>
    <video key="13"/>
    <video key="41"/>
    <video key="61"/>
  </videos>
  <contents>
    <content key="13"/>
    <content key="41"/>
    <content key="61"/>
    <content key="10"/>
  </contents>
</root>
```